# Spring Tool Suite - 3.9.5 - central maven repo - re-indexing

Tags: maven, spring-tool-suite

I have been trying to do rebuilding the-index central maven repository in STS - 3.9.5, But re building the index doesn't even start to work. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean by re-indexing?

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, my bad. I should have said Rebuilding the index,

Comment: This, I found on an instructional video, where they were rebuilding the index under global repository (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Comment: I guess that your issue is that you have a dependency and maven fails to resolve that dependency. Have you tried searching for that dependency on [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/)? I personally never heard of "Rebuilding the index" of Maven Central and I find it a bit strange since the repository is not *your* repository, it's hosted by apache. I therefore don't see why *you* would need to index maven central

Comment: Oh okay, I'm a fresher to software development. I will try search.maven.org. From what I understood, the instructor was downloading all the plugins through that rebuild-index option, and so he was able to select any plugin he wanted to include in the project, just by searching it in the 'Add maven plugin' option in STS

Comment: I'm not sure if I can post that video here, if I may, please do tell me. I will share that video link, where he does that. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, it starts to make sense. STS (which uses Eclipse) has a lokal index of Maven Central to allow it to search maven central quicker. In the worst case, you can add your plugin to the file called `pom.xml` manually. What plugin do you need?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I need plugins for jetty server

Comment: The local index in Eclipse is downloaded from Central...

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't respond earlier. Do you mean [this plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html)?